# Python webscraper, looping through object list and dynamically changing URLs

Tags: python

I have this code that fetches data from an URL:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
url = 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple'
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')

list = ['M0NESY','S1mple']

listdf = pd.DataFrame(list)
listdf.index = listdf.index + 1
print(listdf)

stammdaten = dict( (e.text, e.find_next_sibling('div').text) for e in soup.select('.infobox-description'))
stammdaten['nickname'] = url.split('/')[-1]

#creating a dataframe
index = [1]
stammdatendf = pd.DataFrame(stammdaten, columns = ['nickname', 'Role:','Born:'], index=index)
print(stammdatendf)

#exporting data into Excel
stammdatendf.to_excel('test.xlsx')
```

It works for a static URL that is predefined in the code, however I would like the code to loop through the items in `list`, dynamically change the URL based on that and output the results for the `nickname`, `Role:` and `Born:` in my dataframe.

Unfortunately, I'm a bit lost on how to achieve that. I understand that I should create a loop command, but my attemtps at doing so have failed so far.

Editing here:

Basically what I'm trying to achieve is something like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}
urls = ['https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple', 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/M0NESY', 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/Dexter']
players = []
for url in urls:
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
    stammdaten = dict( (e.text, e.find_next_sibling('div').text) for e in soup.select('.infobox-description'))
    stammdaten['nickname'] = url.split('/')[-1]
    players.append(stammdaten)
    #print(players)

#creating a player DataFrame
playerdf = pd.DataFrame(players, columns =['nickname','Born:','Role:'])
print(playerdf)
```

However instead of the `urls` array I would like to use an already existing array that contains the names of all players.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamically changing urls? Are you writing a web crawler that reads the content of a page, then jumps to another page and reads IT's content?  IS changing the target URL what you mean by dynamically changing the url?

Comment: Yes, exactly. That's what I'm trying to achieve. The script is supposed to output that information in an excel sheet.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're trying to figure out how to navigate liquidpedia using beautiful soup to scrape player profiles.

In this response, I'll be creating a scrape profile for `M0NESY`'s profile page at `https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/M0NESY`

## Examine The Page Structure

My first step would be to examine the structure of the static document that's being served. If you right click `Name:` for example

[image: https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/M0NESY]

and click **inspect**. Developer tools should open up.
You inspect and understand the structure of the HTML page and its design to build custom scrapers.

It seems that this developer isn't making it too easy for us.

[image]

Typically they'd include an `id` or `class` tag to make it easy to find.

They don't even use `table` elements. They just have a repetitive structure for each row that looks like this.

[image]

## Create a Strategy to extract specific items

My approach will be:

- Find all `divs`
- select the div that contains `Name:`
- Grab the parent
- This first child was `Name:`, Grab the second child element from the parents which contains `Илья Осипов`

That would look something like this:

```py
def extract_player_info_from_liquipedia_bs4(content:bs4.BeautifulSoup, descriptor):
    """
    There are no specific tags or classes for that data. Kind of annoying. 
    The structure for that profile table seems to be
     
    div:
        div with a description like "Name"
        div with the details    

    """    
    # find all divs
    divs = content.select("div")
    
    # focus on the one that has the word "Name:" in it
    info_divs = list(filter(lambda x: descriptor in x, divs))  #this sorts through all divs and only returns a list of the divs with the word "Name:" in them.
    
    # find its parent 
    parent = info_divs[0].parent
    
    #parent will have two children, The description and the value
    second_child_with_details = parent.select("div")[1]
    
    return second_child_with_details.contents[0]
```

There will be small variations in the quality of output.

For example:

- If I run this on `Name:` it will get me `Олександр Олегович Костилєв`
- If I run it on `Nationality` it will get me something like `"<span class="flag"><a href="/counterstrike/Category:Ukraine" title="Ukraine"><img alt="Ukraine" decoding="async" height="24" loading="lazy" src="/commons/images/b/bb/Ua_hd.png" width="36"/></a></span>"`

The latter needs some refinement to make it human readable/text readable.

For specific fields, I create specific functions to clean them.

```py
def clean_nationality_description(nationality_description):
    """
    Turns:
    "<span class="flag"><a href="/counterstrike/Category:Ukraine" title="Ukraine"><img alt="Ukraine" decoding="async" height="24" loading="lazy" src="/commons/images/b/bb/Ua_hd.png" width="36"/></a></span>"
    into
    "Ukraine"    
    """
    nationality = nationality_description.a.get("title")
    return nationality
```

## Create a script that loops over profiles

Builds a dataframe per profile, and then adds it to a larger dataframe. Once you've run through all players, it will save to a `csv` which should open fine in excel.

```py
import bs4  

import requests
import pandas as pd

def get_page_content(url):
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, 'html.parser')
    return soup

def extract_player_info_from_liquipedia_bs4(content:bs4.BeautifulSoup, descriptor):
    """
    There are no sepcific tags or classes for that data. Kind of annoying. 
    The structure for that profile table seems to be
     
    div:
        div with the description like "Name"
        div with the details    

    """    
    # find all divs
    divs = content.select("div")
    
    # focus on the one that has the word "Name:" in it
    info_divs = list(filter(lambda x: descriptor in x, divs))  #this sorts through all divs and only returns a list of the divs with the word "Name:" in them.
    
    # find its parent to find the actual name.
    parent = info_divs[0].parent
    
    #parent will have tow children, The description and the val ue
    second_child_with_details = parent.select("div")[1]
    
    return second_child_with_details.contents[0]


def clean_born_description(born_description):
    """ 
    Turns:
    "May 1, 2005 (age 17)"
    into:
    "May 1, 2005"
    """
    
    born = born_description.split("(")[0].strip()
    return born

def clean_nationality_description(nationality_description):
    """
    Turns:
    "<span class="flag"><a href="/counterstrike/Category:Ukraine" title="Ukraine"><img alt="Ukraine" decoding="async" height="24" loading="lazy" src="/commons/images/b/bb/Ua_hd.png" width="36"/></a></span>"
    into
    "Ukraine"    
    """
    nationality = nationality_description.a.get("title")
    return nationality



players = ["M0NESY", "S1mple"]
player_tables = pd.DataFrame([], columns = ["handle", "name", "romanized","born", "nationality"])

for loop_index, player_name in enumerate(players): 
    url = 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/' + player_name
    content = get_page_content(url)


    name                      = extract_player_info_from_liquipedia_bs4(content=content, descriptor = "Name:")
    romanized                 = extract_player_info_from_liquipedia_bs4(content=content, descriptor = "Romanized Name:")

    __born_description        = extract_player_info_from_liquipedia_bs4(content=content, descriptor= "Born:")
    __nationality_description = extract_player_info_from_liquipedia_bs4(content=content, descriptor= "Nationality:")


    born        = clean_born_description(__born_description)
    nationality = clean_nationality_description(__nationality_description)

    # build a dataframe
    data = dict( name = [name],
                 romanized = [romanized],
                 born = [born],
                 nationality = [nationality], 
                 handle = [player_name])

    player_info = pd.DataFrame(data, index = [loop_index])
    
    # concat it with our table
    player_tables = pd.concat( [player_tables, player_info]) 
    

player_tables.to_csv("Players.csv")
```

Answer (score 0):

It is my belief that you understand the basics of beautiful soup usage, but you're lacking a structured intuition about how to create crawlers. Assuming you know how functions, if-statements, and loops work, I've written up psuedo-code that should work with some modification. Look for the parts that say `TODO` and edit those.

```py
import pandas as pd

visited_urls = []
urls_to_visit = []
forbidden_urls = []# list of urls that would lead your crawler into places that are NOT relevant. Like home page. About us page, etc

COLUMNS = [] # TODO: Find column names will exist in all pages that you're scraping

def get_urls_in_url(url):
    list_of_urls_for_page = []
    """TODO: Get Beautiful soup to generate a list of urls. 
    Additionally make sure you filter out all the urls that are not importan here
    The goal of this function is to exstract only those URL's that will provide you the information you need
    """
    return list_of_urls_for_page
  

def get_the_data_you_need_from_page(url):
    df = df.DataFrame(COLUMNS)
    """TODO: Scrape the data. Put it in the columns you need. If the data doesn't exist. Then return an empty data frame"""
    return df


def crawl(initial_url):
    urls_to_visit.append(initial_url)
    
    all_data = pd.DataFrame(COLUMNS)
    
    while True:        
        if len(urls_to_visit) == 0:
            break
        
        url_of_interest = urls_to_visit.pop(0) # takes the first url off the list]
        visited_urls.append(url_of_interest) #mark this url as visited
        
        print(f"Visiting {url_of_interest}...")
        
        # Deal with Data on that page
        print(f"Extracting Data from {url_of_interest}")
        page_data = get_the_data_you_need_from_page(url = url_of_interest)
        all_data.append(page_data, ignore_index = True)
        
        # Deal with URL on that page
        print(f"Extracting URLs from {url_of_interest}")
        page_urls = get_urls_in_url(url=url_of_interest)
        
        for url in page_urls:
            if url not in visited_urls and url not in forbidden_urls:
                print(f"Adding {url} to urls worth visiting")
                urls_to_visit.append(url)
            else:
                print(f"Ignoring: {url}")

    #if you've run out of urls to visit, you'll reach this part of the crawl() funtion
    return all_data  

if __name__ == "__main__":
    target_url = "https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike/S1mple"
    
    data = crawl(initial_url= target_url) #crawls, builds up a dataframe of information. 
    
    data.to_csv("text.csv")
```

The program starts at `if __name__ == "__main__":`
It calls `crawl()` which crawls the urls.

Comment: Hey, thanks for your help. Is a crawler really what I would need in this case? Since I have a pre-defined list of Players (and by that URLs) that I want to extract the information for (in this case, only 2). For my general use case, I would need to extract the information from ~50 URLs that I have predefined.

Comment: No A cralwer would be for a different use case. In this case, I would work on the problem specification before I write any more code.  

For example: 
I have a list of 50 urls. They have structured data that I'd like to extract from it and add to a pandas dataframe. One row per page. Then I'd like to save the dataframe to an excell sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I went a different route, have a look:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/110.0.0.0 Safari/537.36'}

url_base = 'https://liquipedia.net/counterstrike'
player_usernames = df['Nickname']

playersli = []
for p in player_usernames:
    url = f'{url_base}/{p}'
    soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url, headers=headers).text, 'html.parser')
    stammdaten = dict( (e.text, e.find_next_sibling('div').text) for e in soup.select('.infobox-description'))
    stammdaten['Nickname'] = url.split('/')[-1]
    playersli.append(stammdaten)

#creating a player DataFrame
playerdf = pd.DataFrame(playersli, columns = ['Nickname','Born:','Role:']
```